# Textures not being applied via UV coordinates

Tags: libgdx

I am converting a simple three.js scene that I have to libgdx. Everything loads and runs fine, however it seems that the UV texture coordinates for my objects are not being applied correctly? I am using .obj/.mtl for model and texture. I know in the tutorial it was stated that in production one should use the .g3db format vs the .obj format and I plan to do so, but I'm still curious as to why the textures are not being mapped correctly for my .objs? Has anyone seen this happen before? Am I just missing something?

**LIBGDX**

[image]

**THREEJS**

[image]

```
package com.freedom.thirty;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.PerspectiveCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.VertexAttributes.Usage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.Environment;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.Model;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.ModelBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.ModelInstance;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.attributes.ColorAttribute;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.environment.DirectionalLight;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.Material;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.utils.CameraInputController;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.utils.ModelBuilder;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.FPSLogger;


public class FreedomThirty implements ApplicationListener {

    public PerspectiveCamera cam;
    public CameraInputController camController;
    public ModelBatch modelBatch;
    public AssetManager assets;
    public Array<ModelInstance> allModelInstances = new Array<ModelInstance>();
    public Environment environment;
    public boolean loading;

    public Array<ModelInstance> players = new Array<ModelInstance>();
    public ModelInstance player;


    public ModelInstance board;
    public ModelInstance skybox;

    public FPSLogger theLogger = new FPSLogger();

    @Override
    public void create() {
        modelBatch = new ModelBatch();
        environment = new Environment();
        environment.set(new ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight, 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1f));
        environment.add(new DirectionalLight().set(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, -1f, -0.8f, -0.2f));

        cam = new PerspectiveCamera(45, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        cam.position.set(-4f, 4f, 4f);
        cam.lookAt(5f, 0f, -5f);
        cam.near = 1f;
        cam.far = 1000f;
        cam.update();

        camController = new CameraInputController(cam);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(camController);

        assets = new AssetManager();
        assets.load("test_character.obj", Model.class);
        assets.load("meter_grid.obj", Model.class);
        assets.load("skybox1.obj", Model.class);
        loading = true;        

    }

    private void doneLoading(){

        skybox = new ModelInstance(assets.get("skybox1.obj", Model.class));

        board = new ModelInstance(assets.get("meter_grid.obj", Model.class));
        allModelInstances.add(board);

        player = new ModelInstance(assets.get("test_character.obj", Model.class));
        allModelInstances.add(player);
        players.add(player);


        loading = false;        

    }

    @Override
    public void render() {

        if(loading && assets.update()){
            doneLoading();
        }

        camController.update();

        Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        modelBatch.begin(cam);
        modelBatch.render(allModelInstances, environment);
        if(skybox != null){
            modelBatch.render(skybox);
        }
        modelBatch.end();

        theLogger.log();

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

        modelBatch.dispose();
        allModelInstances.clear();
        assets.dispose();

    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to flip the coordinates, see: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Coordinate-systems#pixmap-and-texture-coordinates

Comment: @Xoppa This was indeed the solution. Comment up-voted. If you would like to move this into an answer I will accept. Many Thanks :)